# Interacting with Rails App PostgreSQL Database in Dev Mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, spree

I have what I hope is a fairly simple question:

I've recently taken over as webmaster for a small company, and I'm admittedly new to a lot of this stuff.  Basically, I've set up a local version of the company's web app for development, and everything in the app works as expected until I try to navigate to product pages, at which point I'm met with a 'Page Not Found' error.  I'm guessing I haven't configured something related to the DB correctly, but I'm not sure what.  As I said, I'm pretty new to all this stuff.

We're currently using Ruby 1.9.3, PostgreSQL 9.1.3, and Spree storefront 1.1.1.

Thanks.

***EDIT:***

When I try to log into the admin panel I'm told that I'm using an invalid email/password.  The development.log file records the following when attempting to access product pages:

```
Started GET "/t/category/bedding" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-22 23:31:35 -0800
Processing by Spree::TaxonsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"category/bedding"}
[1m[35mSpree::Taxon Load (1.6ms)[0m  SELECT "spree_taxons".* FROM "spree_taxons" 
WHERE      "spree_taxons"."permalink" = 'category/bedding' LIMIT 1
Rendered public/404.html (0.4ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 13ms (Views: 5.0ms | ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)
```

Comment: do you have any data in your DB? looks like it is empty - no user admin record, no taxons

Comment: I realized what was wrong: I thought that the db had already been populated with data, but, alas, I was wrong!  The db was empty.  I just did a `pg_dump` from the production server and setup the db locally.  Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1):

Spree displays "page not found" if ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound is raised, so yes, you might be right. But if there was some major issue with DB configuration, your would not be able to do anyting with app, it would crash immediately.

Can you see any products in admin section? Where did you get initial DB data? Try inspecting log/development.log file (I'd recommend to clear it before visiting products page to get rid of everything else). There might be some query that fails and results in "page not found"